# In technical analysis why higher volumes are considered better for a price action

Tags: stock-markets, technical-analysis, chart

I have read everywhere that, if a chart pattern gets broken by a higher volume of trades then its considered better than the same pattern broken with lower number of trades.
But I have never seen a reason to why is that so?

Also, I know above is correct but here is my counterpoint:

Lets say on a day a chart pattern shows volume of:
A. 100 trades
B. 10000 trades
and the price action was same (rise/fall in the price of the commodity). Lets say of 5% up

In option A mostly all percentages of trades are contributing to the rise in the price
ie. less number of trades were able to increase the price of the commodity by 5%.
When we compare this to the option B where although there were many trades but the price action was similar to option A implying many people were selling the commodity for less price as well?

Comment: I agree with your assessment that 'high volume of trades' can be interpreted in different  ways and has a number of different components. But it would seem to make sense.  I would also be interested in seeing empirical evidence on whether or not this is true.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow the question.  In every trade, someone is buying and someone is selling.  If there are 100 trades, there were 100 buyers and 100 sellers.  If there are 10,000 trades, there are 10,000 buyers and 10,000 sellers.